# Serverless error UPDATE_FAILED - AWS::IAM::Role - IamRoleLambdaExecution

Tags: deployment, serverless

When deploying a lambda using serverless I am getting the following error when running `sls deploy -s dev -v`:

```
UPDATE_FAILED - AWS::IAM::Role - IamRoleLambdaExecution 

 Serverless Error ----------------------------------------

  An error occurred: IamRoleLambdaExecution - The policy failed legacy parsing (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: b80c863c-1a49-43ae-887c-9611c869e08c; Proxy: null)
```

[image: Image with the full log]

Answer (score 1):

This error was caused by a resource incorrectly written.

I had a resource as:

```
arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:982028098624/bigtier-dev-sqs
```

and it had to be:

```
arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:982028098624:bigtier-dev-sqs
```

It took me hours to find it (the error message didn't help), that's why I wanted to share it. If you get this error, read every resource char by char!